# Spring @RequestBody Content type not supported

Tags: spring

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(name="/example", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String example(@RequestBody String request) {
        System.out.println("example: " + request);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

And request (linux console):

```
curl -i -X POST 'https://localhost/example' -k -d 'name=value'
```

And spring console output:

```
example: name=value
```

But when I use @RequestBody Request request instead of @RequestBody String  It doesn't work:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleCtrl {
    @RequestMapping(name="/example", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String example(@RequestBody Request request) {
        System.out.println("example: " + request);
        return "OK";
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class Request {
    private String name;

    public Request() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

**EDIT**
Resolved. It works when I use

```
curl -i -X POST 'https://localhost/example' -k -d '{"name": "value"}' --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Answer (score 1):

according to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

> You convert the request body to the method argument by using an
>   `HttpMessageConverter`. `HttpMessageConverter` is responsible for
>   converting from the HTTP request message to an object and converting
>   from an object to the HTTP response body. The
>   `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` supports the `@RequestBody` annotation with
>   the following default `HttpMessageConverters`:
>
> `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` converts byte arrays.
>
> `StringHttpMessageConverter` converts strings.
>
> `FormHttpMessageConverter` converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.
>
> `SourceHttpMessageConverter` converts to/from a
>   javax.xml.transform.Source.

so perhaps the `request` argument is not a simple String (Specially you are using `POST`) and couldn't be converted.